# Обязательно закрывать после чтения из файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Обязательно после чтения из файла закрывать его?
В каких случаях открыть и закрыть файл нужно?

```py
a = open("score.txt")
playerscore = float(a.read())
# a.close()
```

Comment: Обязательно, иначе можно случайно оставить много открытых файлов и компьютер может заявить что их слишком много

Comment: Ясно, если открыл, не важно для чего, то после действий над ним, надо обязательно закрыть! Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если открыл - закрой. Но лучше использовать конструкцию with/as 
Пример:

```
PATHFILE = "somewhere/rightHere/yoreMagaFile.txt"
magicWords = "it is a good day to die"


def fileWriter(text):
    with open(PATHFILE, 'w') as writeFile:
        writeFile.write(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fileWriter(magicWords)
```

Это, вроде как, бестпрактис :)